# How to map different column values to one column

Tags: pandas, mapping

I have a data frame below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"SK":["EYF","EYF","RMK","MB","RMK","GYF","RMK","MYF"],
               "SA":["a","b","tm","tmb","tm","cd","tms","alb"],
               "C":["","11","12","13","","15","16","17"]})
df
```

[image]

I want to map some values of "SK","SA" and "C" to a new column:

```
df["D"]= df["SK"].map({"EYF":1,"MB":2,"GYF":3})
df
```

[image]

```
df["D"]= df["SA"].map({"tm":4})
df
```

[image]

```
df["D"]= df["C"].map({"16":5,"17":6})
df
```

[image]

But when I run the next map function, "D" column values mapped by previous map function turn to NaN.
I wanna get df below:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 3 Series and then replace misisng values from previous `Series` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
a = df["SK"].map({"EYF":1,"MB":2,"GYF":3})
b = df["SA"].map({"tm":4})
c = df["C"].map({"16":5,"17":6})

df["D"] = a.fillna(b).fillna(c)
#alternative
df["D"] = a.combine_first(b).combine_first(c)
print (df)
   SK   SA   C    D
0  EYF    a      1.0
1  EYF    b  11  1.0
2  RMK   tm  12  4.0
3   MB  tmb  13  2.0
4  RMK   tm      4.0
5  GYF   cd  15  3.0
6  RMK  tms  16  5.0
7  MYF  alb  17  6.0
```

Order is important for priority if same match for some value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"SK":["EYF","EYF"],
               "SA":["a","tm"],
               "C":["16","17"]})

a = df["SK"].map({"EYF":1,"MB":2,"GYF":3})
b = df["SA"].map({"tm":4})
c = df["C"].map({"16":5,"17":6})

df["D1"] = a.fillna(b).fillna(c)
df["D2"] = b.fillna(a).fillna(c)
df["D3"] = c.fillna(b).fillna(a)
print (df)
    SK  SA   C  D1   D2  D3
0  EYF   a  16   1  1.0   5
1  EYF  tm  17   1  4.0   6
```